# Conditional Sum values in mysql query

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sum

i have a mysql table that contains `services for invoices`.

it looks like

`servicename|ammount|price|tag(type of service)|discount(service worthy of discount, true or false)|clientDiscount(client worthy of discount, true or false)`

I need to make a query that `groups by year`, `sums(amount * price)`

But, if `discount` and `clientDiscount` are `true` i need to count for a `discount of 15%`

I have tried with case and `if statements` but nothing works. I don't really
know witch end to start in. And to be honest i can't really grasp how case and if statements work. I think i need to make one Sum that contains services with discount true and client discount true, then another sum that includes the services without discounts and add these upp to get a correct sum? Right now its like an ant farm in my head.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could aggregate it without `if`. `discount` and `clientdiscount` are integers, so you may simply multiply it with your discount percent. Slightly modified script of @pala:

```
select year(invoicedate), sum(amount * price * (1 - discount * clientdiscount * 0.15)) total
  from invoices
  group by year(invoicedate);
```

Comment: due to associativity, `1 - discount * clientdiscount * 0.15` becomes `1-0` if either `discount` or `clientdiscount` are 0. and `1 - 0.15` if they are both `1`.

Comment: @Jesper It's simple arithmetics. Value * (1 - 0.15) = Value * 0.85. discount and clientdiscount may be equal to 0 or 1. When both are equal to 1 you have to apply a discount. When one (or both) is 0, you have not to apply the discount. So, in the first case you will get Value * (1 - 1 * 1 * 0.15) = Value * 0.85. In the second case - Value * (1 - 0 * 0.15) = Value * 1 = Value.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
select year(invoicedate), sum(amount * price * if(discount and clientdiscount, 0.85, 1)) total
  from invoices
  group by year(invoicedate);
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d96a9/1)

The `if` statement works like this. `if(condition, value-if-true, value-if-false)`.  So in your example, if `discount and clientdiscount` is true (ie, they are both 1), it will return your discount amount of `15%` (a discount of `X` is the same as multiplying by `1 - X`).  If the condition is false, it will return `1`, which won't modify the result of `amount * price`.  In summary, after the `if` is processed, the `sum` becomes either:
`sum(amount * price * 0.85) -- if discount and client discount are both 1`
OR
`sum(amount * price * 1) -- if discount and client discount are both 0`

Comment: Probably a dum question, but the values in my discount, clientDiscount columns are true and false not 1 or 0. Its easy to change though. But can it work as is with true or false value?

Comment: I LOVE YOU!!!!!!! Im almost there. Ive made two fields "as total" and " as totaldiscount", is it possible to make a sum of these two like sum(total - totaldiscount) as final? Here is a link to where i am now. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee57c/2/0  I get an error saying there is now total.

Comment: you can't refer to field aliases in the select clause, you would need to expand total and totaldiscount to the formula used to create them. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee57c/5